# GIT - Unable to revert the project state to specific revision in History

Tags: java, git

I justed messed up my GIT Remote Repository and Local repository by updating the current code with older commit using `git checkout <revision-no>.`

Assume that I am at commit state A-B-C-D and I want to revert the complete project state to B, which means I want same package structure and files as it was pushed to B. Is there a way to do this?

I tried `git reset --hard HEAD`, unfortunately I am still seeing files committed at level D in my local repository and remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are in a "detached state" since you did a `git checkout {commitId}`.

This may work:
`git checkout master` and then
`git reset --hard {commitId of B}`

Comment: I want the completed project state to be same as in commit B. But in this cas, I still see packages from commit D. Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In general, git checkout is for updating(reverting) the local working files and modifying the position of the HEAD pointer. It can be used for looking at previous commits and switching branches without actually changing anything in the project. git reset is for actually modifying a branch pointer to revert a project branch to an earlier commit. At this point, your HEAD is still pointing to an earlier commit.  So you need to set it back to end of the current branch:

```
git checkout <branch name>
```

Comment: The changes are already in remote respository, so when I do a checkout , I am still seeing the package and files of commit D

Comment: I see.  I don't think you're supposed to revert a remote git repository to a previous state like you seem to want.  You're supposed to just push editss to a remote server.

Comment: Safest thing to do is to make the changes by hand and push as a new commit.  Moving HEAD and branch pointers around using checkout and reset are only useful locally.  It's assumed that remote branches only go forward.  It shouldn't be too hard if you have all commits stored locally.

Comment: Finally did a manual code change check and pushed as new commit. Thank you for quick reply